# PHP script loading forever and not showing output

Tags: php

I tried to figure out where the problem is all day long now, I wrote some PHP code to embed text in a given image. I place every 3 letters in each pixel by using its ASCII value as RGB values. My problem is that when I launch the script it keeps loading forever. I guess I have some problems with my code but I am unable to figure it out, the debugger didn't help very much as well. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg ("https://dataencrypt.xyz/testimage.jpg"); 
$data = "abcdefghi"; //example
if($q=strlen($data)%3!=0){
    $q==1?$data.="--":$data.="-";
}
if($img!=false){
    for($i = 0;$i<(strlen($data)-3);$i+3){
        $part = substr ($data , $i,3  );
        $color = getEncryptedColor($img,$part);
        imagesetpixel($img, $i,$i, $color);
    }
}
 $decrypted = decryptDataFromImage($img,0,0); // get the first 3 letters.
 echo "".$decrypted;
imagedestroy($img);

function getEncryptedColor($img,$string){
    return imagecolorallocate($img, ord($string[0]), ord($string[1]), ord($string[2]));
}
function printImageValues($image,$num){
    for($x = 0;$x<$num;$x++){
        echo "\n".imagecolorat($image, $x, $x);
    }
    echo "--END--";
}
function decryptDataFromImage($img,$x,$y){
    $currpixel = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($img, $currpixel);
    $str = "".chr($colors["red"]).chr($colors["green"]).chr($colors["blue"]);
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Comment: Might not be the only problem, but that first loop isn't ever going to exit - you need to use `$i+=3 instead of $i+3`

Comment: The only loop you have is in `printImageValues` but I can't see where you call that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop runs forever because you wrote `$i+3`, instead of assigning that value to `$i`, which would be `$i = $i + 3`

So change this part:

`for($i = 0;$i<(strlen($data)-3);$i+3)`

into

`for($i = 0;$i<(strlen($data)-3);$i+=3)`

Comment: Actually the answer is in the first comment!(Just wanted to let you know)

Comment: Wow thank's a lot man, can't belive i didn't notice that until now. You just maid my day.